# Validate Post Data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sql-injection, model-validation

I have this controller method below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserDetails userdetails)
```

What did I do so far ?

1. Replaced potential SQL Candidates in my form (via JQuery side , eg. replace '&' by 'amp')
2. I have added `ModelState.IsValid()` in ServerSide to check.

Are these two checks enough or How should I make sure that `userDetails.UserName` is **free from Injected SQL** ? (Like 1=1 SQL Injection attacks)

Comment: You also need to use parameterized query.

Comment: @Win: can you please elaborate or provide a link ?

Comment: How do you plan to access database - ADO.NET or ORM like EF or Dapper?

Comment: it is generally recommended to not try these on your own. Just let the frameworks built for this, to do this for you. These are built for years do perform these tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Entity Framework, Dapper or regular parameterized query should be sufficient enough.

Comment: I'm already using Entity framework. Does it mean, EF is free from SQL Injection Attacks altogether ?

Comment: Yes if you are using parameterized queries or LINQ.

Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries, LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL injection attacks. (ref :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations)